# Some algebra trouble

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I show that

$$
\frac{sa_0-a_1}{s-r} r +\frac{a_1-ra_0}{s-r} s
$$
equals $a_1$?

Comment: No I'm trying to get a<sub>1</sub> from that equation. Somehow I need to simplify that down, that's where the trouble is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\frac{sa_0-a_1}{s-r}\times r+\frac{s(a_1-ra_0)}{s-r}&=\frac{r(sa_0-a_1)+s(a_1-ra_0)}{s-r}\\&=\frac{\color{red}{sra_0}-ra_1+sa_1\color{red}{-sra_0}}{s-r}\\&=\frac{(s-r)a_1}{s-r}\\&=a_1.\end{align}$$

Comment: Just got done editing it to make it look better, I'm just trying to prove that the equation is equal to $a_1$

Comment: @JohnnyAndrea: I edited it. How about that?

Comment: How did you go from step 2 to step 3?

Comment: @JohnnyAndrea: I added a bit. Take a look.

Comment: Thank you, I had to do a extra step, which is the same you did. Thank you

Comment: @JohnnyAndrea: You are welcome.